# Working with functions that return multiple types

Tags: typescript

I'm having a hard time working with functions that return multiple types:

Here's an example

```
function returnM(x: Number): Number | { a: Number; b: Number } | undefined {
  if (x < 10) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
let result: any = returnM(3);

switch (result) {
  case undefined: {
    // do NNN
    break;
  }
  // case Number do XXX
  // case Object {a: Number, b: Number } do YYY
}

console.log(result);
```

I'm trying to find an elegant way to inspect the specific type that's returned and then act accordingly.

Even having to set "result: any " feels like a bit of a hack.

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe `switch (typeof result)`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bohr-zc0k8?file=/src/index.ts - I tried that but didn't have much luck. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: If you're using a union type and you need to be able to do different things with different branches of the union, then you should make it a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `number` instead of `Number`.

```js
function returnM(x: number): number | { a: number; b: number } | undefined {
  if (x < 10) {
    return undefined;
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}

let result = returnM(3);

switch (typeof result) {
  case "undefined": {
    result // type: undefined
    break;
  }
  case "number": {
    result // type: number
    break;
  }
  case "object": {
    result // type: { a: number; b: number }
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your return type looks exactly like your demo code, then `switch(typeof result)` is possible:

```js
function returnM(x: Number): Number | { a: Number; b: Number } | undefined {
  if (x < 10) {
    return undefined;
  } else if(x < 20) {
    return {"a":10,"b":Number(x)-10};
  } else {
    return x;
  }
}
let result: any = returnM(Math.random()*40);

switch (typeof result) {
  case "undefined":
    console.log("undefined is returned");
    break;
  case "number":
    console.log("A number is returned");
    break;
  case "object":
    console.log("An object is returned");
}

console.log(result);
```

[online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-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-AqUcqCOAorjSG2TjiTowxYPoKAIIg0LCJcckSBJ0SMYY+LzIwLBsFqQQlEAA)

Comment: Thanks. My real world case has multiple return object structures but this gives me a good start. I was hoping there was a cleaner way, but it doesn't sound like it.